# C#, windows form, StremWriter, Header line

Tags: c#, csv, header, streamwriter

I am trying to add a header in my running csv file log. This is what I want,

Project Name, Project SN, Project Build < first Row that will never change, unless file was deleted. In that case create a new header line.

After that row, I want the data to be added to next line every time.

Here is what I have so far.

// Write to CSV
string path =
if (!File.Exists(path))
{
File.CreateText(path);

```
        }

        string projectName = ProjectName_TextBox.Text;
        string projetcBuild = ProjectBuild_TextBox.Text;
        string projectSN = SN_TextBox.Text;
        string header = "Project Name, Project Build, Project SN\n";

        
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path, true)) // true for appending data to file, false to overwrite in file
        {
           
            sw.WriteLine(header);
            
           
            sw.WriteLine(string.Format(projectName + "," + projetcBuild.ToString() + "," + projectSN.ToString()));
            
            
        }
```

What this does is it adds the header and data each time a button is clicked. I want the header added to the file only once. Only the data from form will get appended to next line which I think I have. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File.CreateText returns you a streamwriter; you can use it and also take the opportunity to write the header

```
string header = "Project Name, Project Build, Project SN\n";

// Write to CSV string path
try{
  StreamWriter sw;

  if (!File.Exists(path)) {
    sw = File.CreateText(path);
    sw.WriteLine(header);
  } else
    sw = File.AppendText(path);

  string projectName = ProjectName_TextBox.Text;
  string projetcBuild = ProjectBuild_TextBox.Text;
  string projectSN = SN_TextBox.Text;
 
  sw.WriteLine(projectName + "," + projetcBuild + "," + projectSN);
            
}
finally{
  sw.Dispose(); 
}
```

You don't need to call ToString on a string. You don't need to call format on a string with no placeholders. You shouldn't really bother writing your own csv writer; there are so many good libraries out there that does it. This simple implementation will fall down as soon as someone puts a comma in one of the textboxes

Comment: Hey Caius Jard, thanks for you reply, are you saying that the simple implementation will fall with your code or with what I have once someone puts a comma?

Comment: Either; both your code and mine make no attempt to quote the fields, for example.. I would say "you can fix it like ... " but honestly, CSV writer libs exist and are free; you might well be better off using someone else's wheel than inventing your own.. Example: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/writing/appending-to-an-existing-file/

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the file exists before adding headers using File.Exists(path). Something like

```
    string projectName = ProjectName_TextBox.Text;
    string projetcBuild = ProjectBuild_TextBox.Text;
    string projectSN = SN_TextBox.Text;
    string header = "Project Name, Project Build, Project SN\n";

    var firstWrite = !File.Exists(path);
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path, true)) // true for appending data to file, false to overwrite in file
    {
       if(firstWrite)
        sw.WriteLine(header);
        
       
        sw.WriteLine(string.Format(projectName + "," + projetcBuild.ToString() + "," + projectSN.ToString()));
```

Comment: I have the file.Exists(Path) bit but not sure what you mean by sw.WriteLine(Header) does this go at the top where I am giving a path = "@C:\...." or below where I am writing data to file?

Comment: Sorry, I'm on mobile so it's hard for me to write the code out. I'm presuming the code snipped you posted is in the scope of the click event being fired. If that's the case, the first time the button is clicked the file won't exist. So you could check if the file exists, assign that to a variable, then only write headers if the file doesn't exist yet. I updated my answer to be more comprehensive

Comment: I updated the code according to you edit above, this actually does not write the header at all. I only see the second line that is being added.

Comment: var headerLine = !File.Exists(path);

            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path, true)) // true for appending data to file, false to overwrite in file
            {
                if (headerLine)
                    sw.WriteLine(header);
                
                    
                sw.WriteLine(string.Format(projectName + "," + projetcBuild.ToString() + "," + projectSN.ToString()));
                
                
            }

Comment: Hey Rye, Thank you for helping me. I know what I was doing wrong. I was checking if file existed 2 times, 1 in the beginning under path, and one below where you showed... I deleted the one under path and it works now with a bit of addition to your code.

Comment: That's great to hear. Would you mind marking my answer as correct if it solved your problem?